# how to read and write the existing excel sheet?

Tags: python-2.7, xlsx, xlrd, xlwt

As I got output total hours and week number reading from one excel sheet,now I should search that week number in another existing excel sheet and filling that total hours in respective week number column in another existing excel sheet,
I should read and write into that existing sheet using xlrd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write to Excel worksheets using *xlwt* (in which case I suppose you have to copy over all the data from the existing sheet manually) or *openpyxl* (more high-level API, but works only with Excel 2010+). See: [Python Excel](http://www.python-excel.org/).

Comment: @doubts: See the link I provided, it lists compatible Excel versions.